# A list of references gets affected when another list is cleared

Tags: c#, list, reference

I have created a list as `PartList`, that a method called `CombinePartList`" creates and returns it. In another method I need this method's results, but also I need to clear the list `PartList`. So I created another list,
but when I clear `PartList` the second one named `MPartList` gets cleared too.
My question is, why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

**Here's my code:**

```
List<ModifiedPartList> PartList = new List<ModifiedPartList>();
List<ModifiedPartList> MpartList= new List<ModifiedPartList>();;
anotherMethode()
{

MpartList = CombinePartListforView(bar, ViewNum);
*
*
*            
PartList.Clear();
}
```

Comment: At some point, you're probably doing `MpartList = PartList`. You seem to have omitted code here, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your snippet doesn't exactly tell what's wrong, but I assume that `CombinePartListforView()` returns a reference to PartList and therefore makes MpartList point to the same instance as PartList. You probably don't want to change the list instances themselves, just the contents.

Try

```
MpartList = new List<ModifiedPartList>(CombinePartListforView(bar, ViewNum));
```

or make sure that you return a new instance in that method.

Answer (score 0):

`MpartList` has a reference to `PartList`. So, when you clear one of them the other would be cleared as will. (**Both refer to the same value**)

As a soulution, I would suggest you to fully copy PartList by using for loop and creating new objects like this:

```
Public List<ModifiedPartList> FullCopy(List<ModifiedPartList> PartList)
{
List<ModifiedPartList> NewList=new List<ModifiedPartList>();
for (int i=0;i<PartList.Count();i++)
{
    NewList.Add(CopyObject(PartList[i]));//Write this function
}
return NewList();
}
```